# Yii2 get text from Db and use them in the Model

Tags: php, controller, yii2, string-formatting

I am trying to search data based on the saved queries. For instance I save the data as mentioned below in my table.

```
'category_id'=>1,'status_id'=>1
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the above data from my table and use them in my controller.

```
$model = MyTable::find()->where([myTable->data])->all();
```

When I try to do the above I get operator requires two operands error. What is the possible way to achieve the result for the above? Thank you

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? Get record/records where `category_id =1` and `status_id = 1` ?

Comment: Yes... I want to get records based on category_id and status_id

Comment: is not clear to me how you have saved  the data .. show the php code  .. and not only a part ..

Comment: what you get in data

Comment: @YasinPatel in myTable->data gets the value from the database i.e 'category_id'=>1, 'status_id'=>1

Comment: you are getting data from i.e.:  'category_id'=>1, 'status_id'=>1  , can you change it to  'category_id="1" and 'status_id="1" '

Comment: because from your data is not complete array and not proper string to make query

Comment: when I retrieve the data it is supposed to be like                           **MyTable::find()->where(['category_id'=>1,'status_id'=>1])->all();**    doesn't that make sense @YasinPatel

Comment: No bro , you are getting 'category_id'=>1, 'status_id'=>1 and you are putting  in query , and it is considering as single variable

Comment: so you mean to say I need to store whole query and get it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`$models = MyTable::find()->where(['category_id' => 1, 'status_id' => 1])->all();`

Comment: That should obviously work... I am storing category_id => 1,'status_id'=>1 in my save_query table. I retrieve them as a string and assign i. myTable refers to table name and data will get the column value.